# based on options selected in first job, how to trigger another job in Jenkins using Dynamic parameter plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 3 Jenkins jobs 'J1', 'J2', 'J3'. Now I have to create another Job 'Jselect' which takes user inputs or a drop down having values J1, J2, J3. Based on the user selection it should trigger the jobs J1 or J2 or J3.

To achieve this, I installed [DynamicParameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in) and created the job 'JSelect'.

In JSelect job, I selected 'This build is parameterized' option and then added a Dynamic Choice Parameter.

Provided the name as : Choose Target Job:

Choices Script as : def list=['J1','J2','J3']

When I Saved and build the job, a dropdown is coming as expected. But Iam not understanding where to capture this input and how to call other jobs based on this input.

I am on the right approach? Can someone please help on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger J1/J2/J3 based on some condition from Jselect.

I suggest you the below approach.

- build step make variable or property file to decide the condition.
  eg(when error ~>5=low ,error ~>15=medium, error ~>50 =high)
- Use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin
  It helps you to select downstream project based on different condition.
  Make sure you uncheecked"trigger build when there is no parameter".

Hope its resolves your issue.